# pandas: how to modify values in a column in dataframe by comparing other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with the following structure:

```
raw_data = {'website': ['bbc.com', 'cnn.com', 'google.com', 'facebook.com'], 
    'type': ['image', 'audio', 'image', 'video'], 
    'source': ['bbc','google','stackoverflow','facebook']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['website', 'type', 'source'])
```

[image]

I would like to modify the values in column `type` with a condition that if the `source` exists in `website`, then suffix `type` with '_1stParty' else '_3rdParty'. The dataframe should eventually look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test values betwen rows with `in` and apply for processing each rows separately:

```
m = df.apply(lambda x: x['source'] in x['website'], axis=1)
```

Or use `zip` with list comprehension:

```
m = [a in b for a, b in zip(df['source'], df['website'])]
```

and then add new values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['type'] += np.where(m, '_1stParty',  '_3rdParty')
#'long' alternative
#df['type'] = df['type'] + np.where(m, '_1stParty',  '_3rdParty')
print (df)
        website            type         source
0       bbc.com  image_1stParty            bbc
1       cnn.com  audio_3rdParty         google
2    google.com  image_3rdParty  stackoverflow
3  facebook.com  video_1stParty       facebook
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply method for this like

```py
df["type"] = df.apply(lambda row: f"{row.type}_1stparty" if row.source in row.website \
                      else f"{row.type}_thirdparty", axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution must be faster than others which use `apply()`:

```
df.type += df.website.str.split('.').str[0].eq(df.source).\
           replace({True: '_1stParty', False: '_3rdParty'})
```